# Extracting multiple file types while ignoring errors

Tags: file-roller

System info:

```
aggitan@moneque:~$ uname -a
Linux moneque 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:05:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

aggitan@moneque:~$ 7z

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
```

I've got a folder that has 68 archives in it ranging from .rar, .ace, & .zip.

I want to extract all of these files using their folder name as the first directory ("Extract here")

If I use file-roller it halts at the first error, there doesn't appear to be an "ignore error" flag for file roller.

If I use 7zip it dumps everything into the current folder and doesn't use clean folders

How can I extract everything into separate folders without spilling everything into the current directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for i in *; do mkdir "$i.extracted"; (cd "$i.extracted" && 7z x "../$i") || echo "Error with $i"; done`

Comment: The simplest of the lot :-)

Comment: I cheated and cross posted this to super user, this is the answer I originally used. http://superuser.com/questions/200640/mass-file-extraction

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any direct solution but with a little bash loop you can do it in a terminal (if, as your question seems to suggest, 7zip is able to do everything you want except for extracting into a folder based on the filename). Try (in the directory with the archives):

```
for FILE in *.*; do DIR=${FILE%.*}; mkdir $DIR && 7z x -o$DIR $FILE ; done
```

The `${FILE%.*}` extracts the filename without the extension.

Comment: you need to `cd $DIR` or otherwise tell 7zip to extract there...

Comment: if there are both `stuff.zip` and `stuff.rar` this will mix up their contents

Comment: The  `-o${FILE%.**}` is telling to use the dir, but I should have reused the `$DIR` variable instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: About `stuff.zip` and `stuff.rar`: That's true, but I think the OP wanted to recreate file-roller's "Extract Here" behaviour which does not create folders like `stuff.zip.extracted` but only uses the filename without the extension.

Comment: that's true, +1ing

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'll try and use this script and the others for similar problems I come along!

Answer (score 3):

A little shell scripting might come to the rescue.

```
#! /bin/bash

for archive in "$@"; do (
    archive_dir="$(cd $(dirname "$archive"); pwd -P)"
    archive_name="$(basename "$archive")"
    # make a directory by appending `.d` to the archive file name
    name="${archive_name}.d"
    mkdir -p "$name"
    cd "$name"
    # extract contents with full path, 
    # replace 'x' with 'e' to extract into $name directory
    7z x "${archive_dir}/${archive_name}"
); done
```

Paste the above into a file `extract.sh` (in the directory where you
want to extract files) and then make it executable:

```
chmod +x ./extract.sh
```

The script creates a directory for each archive given on the command
line by appending `.d` to its file name (e.g., for an archive
`stuff.zip` it will create directory `stuff.zip.d`), and then extracts
files from the archive into it.

You can invoke it in a terminal like this (use wildcards to extract
multiple archives in one go):

```
./extract.sh stuff.zip stuff2.rar
```

*Disclaimer: untested,* so try it out with one or two sample archives
before making the big run.

Comment: if there are both `stuff.zip` and `stuff.rar` this will mix up their contents

Comment: +1. although as Marcel states, that *is* file-roller's behaviour. so it depends on aggitan's exact intentions

Comment: Thank you for the script I'll try and use this in the future.